# Archiving old mongodb documents

Tags: java, json, mongodb

I have a collection that needs to contain only documents from the last 3 months but all the documents should be saved in some way. After some research we thought of the following solution:

a cron every 3 month that execute:

1. find out how many documents need to be archived.
2. archive:  `mongoexport -d MyDB -c MyCollection -q "{ timestamp: {
   \$gt: MyTimestamp}}" -o MyCollection _export_timestamp.json`
3. check how many documents in `MyCollection _export_timestamp.json` and compare with step one
4. delete the archived from the collection.

How can I be sure that the mongo export was successful? if I use java.lang.Process and check the ErrorStream. is this enough?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Java, maybe it would make more sense to use the [MongoDB Java Driver](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/java/)?

You can use the Java API to retrieve the objects to backup, along with a serialization library such as [Kryo](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo) or [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome) for the file output. That would allow you to do anything that you need without worrying about the intricacies of inter-process interaction.